# Are mutable constants safe?

Tags: python, constants, mutability

Are there any sort of 'gotchas' associated with having a constant that is a list, or any other mutable object?

> Currently my context has to do with constants that will be passed to a   call, but I ask the question generically as I don't feel that topic impacts the question meaningfully.

Consider this example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This file was not tested before posting.

import subprocess

LS_FLAGS = ['-l', '-a']

def main():
    subprocess.call(['ls'] + LS_FLAGS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I ask this because I am deathly aware of the problems that an arise from [mutable objects in function definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/1695680); And, even as I understand that there should never be anything doing assignment or mutation to a respected constant; and that "constants" are not really a thing: I ask, and further ask, might there be some conventions for semantically protecting ones self again't accidental mutations?

Comment: You could remove mutation from the equation by using a tuple instead of a list: `LS_FLAGS = ('-l', '-a')` is immutable.  If you must have it as a list when using it later, coerce it to a list with `list(LS_FLAGS)`.  Just note that, while the tuple is immutable, a mutable object within that tuple is still mutable.  This is moot for strings, but if you had lists inside your tuples, you could mutate the lists.

Comment: You could make it a tuple (they're immutable). Or are you asking for something similar to Java's `final` keyword, so you can't assign any different values to a variable after its instantiated?

Comment: I dont think python knows what constants are ...

Comment: I recently blogged about how to make a class where you can't change the attributes as a sort of container for constants... and how it's not really possible. http://www.engyrus.com/2015/02/spt-3-constant-singleton.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having to worry about mutation *can* make code easier to reason about, and as such, it's one of the core tenets of pure functional programming.

In this specific case, it doesn't seem like it would be a serious issue, and might even be argued to be a feature. You can always define `LS_FLAGS` as a tuple if you feel there is no reason for it to be modifiable, but the user of your code can always redeclare `LS_FLAGS` entirely if they like.

Comment: I dunno that I would even have that first paragraph (I gave you +1 cause yours is the most right ...) ... but constants are just variables thats the take away ... its up to the coder to realize maybe I shouldnt change this ALL_CAPS_VARIABLE

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent mutation by accessing your "constants" from a dictionary-like object. Something ''like'' that, maybe:

```
class Config:
    _config = dict(
        LS_FLAGS=['-l', '-a']
    )
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return Config._config[idx].copy()  # Use copy.deepcopy 
                                           # instead if required

CONFIG=Config()
```

Or even:

```
class Config:
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if idx == 'LS_FLAGS':
            return ['-l', '-a']

        raise KeyError(idx)

CONFIG=Config()
```

Then use the `CONFIG` object like that:

```
print(CONFIG['LS_FLAGS'])
```

This is far from perfect (and not very sexy), but this will prevent *accidental*<sup>1</sup>  trashing of your "constants":

```
# Try to mutate the constant config
ls_flags = CONFIG['LS_FLAGS']
ls_flags.append('/home')

print(CONFIG['LS_FLAGS']) # unchanged
```

And

```
CONFIG['LS_FLAGS'] = ['-ls']
```

Will raise `TypeError: 'Config' object does not support item assignment`

---

<sub>¹Of course, as Python does not have "real" constants, that will not protect you against malicious code. For example, one can completely replace the `CONFIG` object...</sub>

Comment: I would use `types.MappingProxyType` https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType